# Convert Umbraco xpath from old schema to new

Tags: c#, api, xpath, umbraco

I have inherited some old code and need to convert to the latest schema in the Umbraco API.

```
private void GenerateDDL()
{
    int currentId = Int32.Parse(umbraco.library.GetXmlNodeCurrent().Current.SelectSingleNode("@id").Value);

    string xpath = string.Format("//node[@id={0}]/descendant::node[@nodeTypeAlias='FormDropdownOption']", currentId);
    XPathNodeIterator xml = umbraco.library.GetXmlNodeByXPath(xpath);

    while (xml.MoveNext())
    {
        //hsEmailList.Add(xml.Current.SelectSingleNode("./data[@alias='Text']").Value.ToString(), xml.Current.SelectSingleNode("./data[@alias='Value']").Value.ToString());
        hsEmailList.Add(xml.Current.SelectSingleNode("Text").Value.ToString(), xml.Current.SelectSingleNode("Value").Value.ToString());
    }
    foreach (DictionaryEntry de in hsEmailList)
    {
        ListItem list = new ListItem();
        list.Text = de.Key.ToString();
        list.Value = de.Value.ToString();
        ddlMemberName.Items.Add(list);
    }
}
```

I need to change from the commented code where it states ./data[@alias='Text'] to the newer schema. Any ideas ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Umbraco new schema" and "Umbraco old schema"? Many people, who are good specialists in XPath and could potentially help, don't know Umbraco. Please, explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
hsEmailList.Add(xml.Current.SelectSingleNode("./data[@alias='Text']").Value.ToString(), xml.Current.SelectSingleNode("./data[@alias='Value']").Value.ToString());
```

to:

```
hsEmailList.Add(xml.Current.SelectSingleNode("./Text").Value.ToString(), xml.Current.SelectSingleNode("./Value").Value.ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that but what about this line: hsEmailList.Add(xml.Current.SelectSingleNode("./data[@alias='Text']").Value.ToString(), xml.Current.SelectSingleNode("./data[@alias='Value']").Value.ToString());